# AWS Elasticache CPU Utilization is different across readers

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an elasticache instance (Cluster mode disabled) on AWS with 1 writer and 5 read replicas spread across different AZs.

We are having load testing of the system and I found that while load testing, CPU utilization is different across each reader. Below is the screenshot of the CPU utilization across all the nodes

[image]

004 is the writer and others are readers.

> You can see that 002 takes 100% CPU while 005 and 006 takes only
> around 50% even when all 3 are in same AZs

So I have the following questions -

1. Why does elasticache not distribute the load equally?
2. If I put more load, will the 005 and 006 instances be able to handle more load?

Comment: You should provide details, whether the node is master/slave. Also number of write/read requests.

Comment: I have written that 004 is master and remaining all are slaves.

Comment: Which Redis client is used here,   Maybe GitHub repo link? Redis itself does not balance out the loads, it's done mostly from application unless some proxy servers are used in between like Twemproxy.

Comment: Also, please share the application config like if you're configuring all 6 nodes or only seed node(s) to discover Redis cluster setup.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticache, per its current documentation, supports up to 5 replica nodes. However, only one DNS endpoint is provided to the replica cluster and AWS routes all traffic from that endpoint to a **single** node.

In addition to that, we don't have any details for how you are connecting to your Elasticache cluster. If you are using a Redis Connection manager that does not have awareness of both your master and secondary node host names or does not support multiple hosts, then your application will not distribute traffic around.

To summarize, you can distribute traffic across the master and a single replica, but without a DNS mapping to your other nodes they are merely backups in case of failure.